# Automake not generating Makefile.in in subdirs

Tags: c++, makefile, autotools, automake

First off I just want to say, I'm a total newb at Autotools.

I have a project with the following structure:

```
+-src
  +-commands
    Makefile.am
    +-copy
      Makefile.am
      copy.h
      copy.cpp
    +-delete
      Makefile.am
      delete.h
      delete.cpp
  main.cpp
  Makefile.am
Makefile.am
```

Makefile.am has SUBDIRS=src

src/Makefile.am has SUBDIRS=commands .

src/commands/Makefile.am has SUBDIRS=$(AUTODIRS)

When I run automake in the root, it generates Makefile.in and src/Makefile.in, but not in commands and copy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure your configure.ac mentions all the Makefiles in AC_CONFIG_FILES.

Comment: Aha. That was it.  Make an answer if you want and I'll choose it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure your configure.ac mentions all the Makefiles in AC_CONFIG_FILES.

Comment: In general, is this something we need to manually add to configure.ac everytime we create a subdirectory and add a new Makefile.am ?

Comment: Yes, when you add a new subdirectory, you will have to update this line in `configure.ac`.  You will also have to add new `SUBDIRS` values in parent directories.