# Automake not generating Makefile.in in subdirectory --- but only on GitHub Actions

Tags: makefile, automake, github-actions

This is similar to the problem mentioned in [Automake not generating Makefile.in in subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058125/automake-not-generating-makefile-in-in-subdirs). However, it is subtly different.

I have a simple project with a `Makefile` in `.` and one in `./tests/`.

In `./Makefile.am` I have:

```
SUBDIRS = tests
```

In `./configure.ac` I have:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile tests/Makefile ])
AC_CONFIG_HEADER([config.h])
```

When I run on MacOS or on Ubuntu 20.04 (locally in a VM), both `./Makefile.in` and `./tests/Makefile.in` are created.

But when I run on GitHub Actions, `tests/Makefile.in` is *not* created.

All systems have similar versions of autoconf, aclocal, libtool, and automake.

So what could be different?